# Connect cakephp 2.4 with redis on centos 6.4 and nginx

Tags: node.js, cakephp, caching, nginx

Well first of all I'm sorry for my bad english, and I hopefully to be answered to my questions.

Good I'll do my question and maybe it's quite complicated, but I'am novice in that topic.

I have an application working on cakephp version 2.4 working on centos 6.4 64 bits with nginx server and working nice.

Now I need to integrate a part of my application with node.js and there is a problem, it's because I need to know the session (File cache) of my cakephp, and I was reading/trying over all the day about to configure each other application and I tried first reading the session files directly only to make a test but I knew it that it wasn't correct because is very insecure and also it's difficult to parse the data and the last reason was it's node.js can't match that user connected to my cakephp application is the same of node.js.

Then reading more about it I saw it's possible to match each application if I use memcached or redis cache and I tried to install memcached and after redis on centos, everything was ok during install but when I tried to put on my cakephp application with this:

### Core.php

$engine = 'Redis';

### bootstrap.php

Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'Redis'));

### Always cakephp give me the next error:

16:58:57 Error: [CacheException] Cache engine default is not properly configured.
Stack Trace:

## 0 /var/www/public_html/project/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('default')

## 1 /var/www/public_html/project/app/Config/bootstrap.php(28): Cache::config('default', Array)

## 2 /var/www/public_html/project/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(92): include('/var/www/public...')

## 3 /var/www/public_html/project/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(177): Configure::bootstrap(true)

## 4 /var/www/public_html/project/app/webroot/index.php(92): include('/var/www/public...')

## 5 {main}

---

And I'm not sure if on nginx I need to configure something about Redis ( About it memcached it was happen the same on cakephp).

On nginx I had the next config:

user              nginx;
worker_processes  2;

error_log         /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid               /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {

```
worker_connections  4000;
# essential for linux, optmized to serve many clients with each thread
use epoll;

# Accept as many connections as possible, after nginx gets notification about  
    #a new connection.
# May flood worker_connections, if that option is set too low.
multi_accept on;
```

}

http {

```
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;

# Caches information about open FDs, freqently accessed files.
# Changing this setting, in my environment, brought performance up from 560k req/sec, to 904k req/sec.
# I recommend using some varient of these options, though not the specific values listed below.
open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s; 
open_file_cache_valid 30s; 
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors on;

#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  dev.project;
    
    client_max_body_size 2m;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/cakeapp.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/cakeapp.error.log;
    rewrite_log on;
    root    /var/www/public_html/project/app/webroot;    
    index   index.php;
 
    # Not found this on disk?
    # Feed to CakePHP for further processing!
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
            break;
    }

    # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    # listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on; # to support 404s for PHP files no$
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess files,
    # git & svn repositories, etc
    location ~ /(\.ht|\.git|\.svn) {
            deny  all;
    }
}

# Compression. Reduces the amount of data that needs to be transferred over 
    # the network
gzip on;
gzip_min_length 10240;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-7]\.";
```

}

Please any tip what I need to do to connect session of cakephp with Redis?

One more thing I tried redis with cli and was working well making a test with set and get and was working ok.

Thanks in advanced.

PD. All of that project is working on a virtual box machine

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. There is one of two things going on. I am not sure that you can configure the cache for Redis with It looks like your configuration is incomplete. I think you need the server parameter. Try copying the Cache config for memcached and updating it for Redis. The other problem could be that Redis isn't running. This was the final issue for me. Start Redis and test again.